# Jetty 9.0 embeded config with SPDY but without SSL/NPN

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, spdy, jetty-9

SSL/NPN will be handled via our loadbalancer (Haproxy), so I don't really need Jetty to do this for us.

But all the examples I can see on the web only show how to do this with SSL/NPN, not without.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
Server server = new Server();
HTTPConfiguration httpConfig = .... // set up some additional http config here
PushStrategey push = new ReferrerPushStrategy();
List<ConnectionFactory> factories = new ArrayList<>();
factories.add(new HTTPSPDYServerConnectionFactory(SPDY.V3, httpConfig, push));
factories.add(new HTTPSPDYServerConnectionFactory(SPDY.V2, httpConfig, push));
factories.add(new HTTPConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, factories.toArray(new ConnectionFactory[factories.size()]));
connector.setPort(port);
server.addConnector(connector);
connector.start();
....
```

Unfortunately, it seems something is wrong, when I try to access the server via clients like curl or my browser they hang indefinitely. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configure a `ServerConnector` to speak clear-text SPDY, your clients must also speak clear-text SPDY.

If you use clients like `curl` or the browser, they don't speak clear-text SPDY. The clients will send a HTTP request which is not understood (the server expects SPDY), and that's why your connection "hangs".

Only Chromium/Chrome has a mode where you can make it speak clear-text SPDY, using the `--use-spdy=no-ssl` parameter as described [here](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-tools-and-debugging).

Therefore, if you're using clear-text SPDY there is no point in configuring multiple `ServerConnectionFactory` because there is no way to select one based on the protocol being negotiated, because there is no protocol negotiation.

The protocol negotiation only happens when using SSL+NPN.

Your code is basically correct (apart the unnecessary multiple `ServerConnectionFactory`) if you really want to setup a clear-text SPDY `ServerConnector`; [this](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-spdy/spdy-http-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/spdy/server/http/AbstractHTTPSPDYTest.java#L81) is an example of how the same is setup in the [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) SPDY test suite.

Finally, see also the [reference documentation about SPDY](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy.html).

Comment: Of course, thanks, that makes sense. Does this mean that I'd have to open separate connectors/ports for each SPDY version we want to support? I guess in this case it makes more sense to implement SPDY along with SSL/NPN on the loadbalancer instead of Jetty though it makes it difficult to implement a useful push strategy in that case.

Comment: Depends on the load balancer.  Those that are able to "tunnel" clear-text SPDY to the backend after having offloaded SSL will allow clients to benefit of the SPDY features in Jetty, such as multiplexing and SPDY push, without cluttering the load balancer with SPDY functionalities.  For example, the [Webtide blogs](https://webtide.intalio.com) are configured in this way, using [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) as load balancer.  I would only advertise one SPDY version in this case; most if not all browsers support SPDY/3, so there is little point in still supporting SPDY/2.

Comment: @sbordet I have a question regarding jetty 9.0 with SPDY but somehow i am not able to figure out. Can we use jetty 9.0 with SPDY along with solr zookeeper? I have been trying to do that but somehow if i add module spdy in jetty 9.0 the zookeeper server would not even start. I would be grateful if you could help me. I have posted a question too about it, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191710/solrcloud-along-with-jetty-9-0-with-spdy-enabled